# Populate Ninja field with slider value

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, hook, ninja-forms

I am trying to include my slider's value :

```
<form action="" method="GET">
<input type="range" min="1" max="12" step="1" value="1" id="passengers" name="passengers" onchange='document.getElementById("bar").value = "Slider Value = " + document.getElementById("passengers").value;'/>
```

in Ninja Forms calculation. So i want the whole calculation to be multiplied by this slider's value - in  real time. I have created a hook to get the slider's value, but it only seems to work if I add submit to it and actually submit the slider's value. I would like it to work real time.

```
 function custom_hook() {
        do_action('custom_hook');
    }


    function slider_values() {
        if(isset($_GET["passengers"])){
        echo .$_GET["passengers"];

    } 
    }
    add_action('custom_hook', 'slider_values', 7);
```

After I have the value working, I would like to populate my ninja field with this:

```
add_action( 'nf_get_form_id', function( $form_id ){
  // Check for a specific Form ID.
  if( 3 !== $form_id ) return;

  add_filter( 'ninja_forms_localize_field_number', function( $field ){
    if( 'number_1539723075044' !== $field[ 'settings' ][ 'key' ] ) return $field;
    // Change the `min` setting of the number field.
      $field[ 'settings' ][ 'value' ] = ['custom_hook'];
    return $field;
  });
} );
```

What am I missing please? 
Is "GET" method only working on form submission?

What is the method to get the value real time, just as I am getting it in my input text below the slider?

Comment: If you want the to update the values in real time you can implement an ajax solution: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: You will need to create custom jquery / javascript function based on the slider value which will do the desired calculation and update the relevant fields. Custom hooks are server side and you will have to post data to that hook to use it. Also, it will have lag which is not a good user experience.